# After closing application, code switches back to an older version in IONIC

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I’m having a problem, where whenever I close the application, both ios and android, when returning, is returning to the previous version.

In IOS it comes back automatically, without me allowing this action.

On ANDROID and displayed a question:
[android screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVXSb.png)

Has anyone ever been through this situation and could you help me?

Comment: No, I have not been, but maybe this is something to do with caching of the builds you deploy, in native development we deploy partial code over the existing one for faster launch, BUT it's not actually the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We updated the version of the code in the ionic repository and the versioning problem stopped happening.